# Restrict role to use a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, user-roles

I want to remove a plugin for a contributor role or just make it unaccessible. I have a code for kinda similar situation:

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_logged_in_plugin' );
function disable_logged_in_plugin( $plugins ) {
    // The 'option_active_plugins' hook occurs before any user information get generated,
    // so we need to require this file early to be able to check for logged in status
    require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
    // If we are logged in, and NOT an admin...
    if ( current_user_can('contributor') & !is_admin() ) {
        // Use the plugin folder and main file name here.
        // is used here as an example
           $plugins_not_needed = array ('/metabox/meta-box.php');
            foreach ( $plugins_not_needed as $plugin ) {
                $key = array_search( $plugin, $plugins );
                if ( false !== $key ) {
                    unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
                }
            }
       PHP            return $plugins;
    }
```

I don't have any experience with php, but how I understand the problem, because they are inside admin area? ( I allow them to Sign up and post, but they aren't admins ).

How can I turn off specific plugin for contributors if they are inside admin area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code disables plugins for logged in users with `contributor` capabilities on non-admin pages. The [`is_admin()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) checks if the current page is "/wp-admin" page, to disable plugins just on the admin pages change this condition to:

`if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) && is_admin() ) {`

But to make this code work you need to have it in [Must-Use plugin](https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-mu-plugins/), to load it earlier than all the plugins. In short, create new PHP file directly inside `/wp-content/mu-plugins` directory, add [required header](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/) information and add your code with the change I mentioned above.

---

Alternatively, you can use a plugin like [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) and disable certain parts of the dashboard to specified users group.